# Converting data in AWS S3 to another schema structure (also in S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

quite a beginner's question -

I have log data stored in S3 files, in zipped JSON format.
The files reside in a directory hierarchy which reflects partitioning, in the following way: `s3://bucket_name/year=2018/month=201805/day=201805/some_more_partitions/file.json.gz`

I recently changed the schema  of the logging to a slightly different directory structure. I Added some more partition levels, the fields currently reside inside of the JSON and I want to move them to the folder hierarchy. Also, I changed the inner JSON schema slightly. They reside in a different S3 bucket.

I wish to convert the old logs to the new format, because I have Athena mapping over the new schema structure.

Is AWS EMR the tool for this? If so, what's the simplest way to achieve this? I thought I need an EMR cluster of type `step execution` but it probably creates just one output file, no?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **Amazon EMR** is an appropriate tool to use.

You could use Hive, which has similar-ish syntax to Athena:

- Create an External Table pointing to your existing data, using your old schema
- Create an External Table pointing to where you wish to store the data, using your new schema
- `INSERT INTO new-table SELECT * FROM old-table`

If your intention is to query the data with Amazon Athena, you can use Amazon EMR to [convert the data into Parquet format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html), which will give even better query performance.

See: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, While searching for an ansewr I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797302/hive-insert-overwrite-and-insert-into-are-very-slow-with-s3-external-table) which says this approach is slow... would you say it's still the best way?

Comment: It's a one-off job, so it doesn't matter if it is slow, as long as it gives you the desired result. Storing your data in partitions (and preferably Parquet or Avro) will speed-up Athena and reduce Athena costs, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes EMR can be used for such conversion.

Here's the sample code where to covert the data coming as csv (stg folder aka source folder) format to orc file format. You may want to do the insert overwrite in case you have overlapping partitions between your staging (aka source) files and Target files

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_stg.stg_table;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `db_stg.stg_table`(
GEO_KEY string,
WK_BEG_DT string,
FIS_WK_NUM Double,
AMOUNT1 Double
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION
  's3://bucket.name/stg_folder_name/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');


drop  table  db_tgt.target_table;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db_tgt.target_table(
GEO_KEY string,
FIS_WK_NUM Double,
AMOUNT1 Double
)
PARTITIONED BY(FIS_WK_NUM)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'

location 's3://bucket.name/tgt_folder_name/'

TBLPROPERTIES (
  'orc.compress'='SNAPPY');

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;


insert overwrite  table  db_tgt.target_table partition(FIS_WK_NUM)
  select
GEO_KEY  ,
WK_BEG_DT ,
FIS_WK_NUM  ,
AMOUNT1   
from  db_stg.stg_table;
```

Agree with John that converting to a columnar file format like Parquet or ORC (along with compression like SNAPPY) will give you the best performance with AWS Athena.

Remember the key to using Athena is to optimize the amount of data  you scan an read. Hence, if the data is in columnar format and you are reading certain partitions, you AWS Athena cost will go down significantly. All you need to do is to make sure you are using the filter condition in your Athena queries that selects the required partitions.